# C Program won't Compile, unsure why

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

Have a Homework for my Intro to C Class. " Write a C program whose input from the keyboard is an array with n elements
(variable-length array) a1; : : : ; an and a value x. Assume that all the values are integer numbers.
The program outputs true if ai + aj = x, for some i ̸= j, and false otherwise."

But my compiler keeps reporting problems in my 1st for loop. I'm sure it's something simple/stupid, someone please point it out? 
Error: "Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in."

Also having an error on my if (number [i] + number [j] = x) { line.
Error: 1value required as left operand of assignment.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (void) {

//Local Declarations
int size;
int number [size];
int x;
bool equality;


//Statements
printf("Enter the size of the array");
scanf("%f", &size);

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) scanf("%f", &number[i]);

printf("Input x.");
scanf("%f", &x);


equality = false;
for (i = 0; i < size && equality = false; i++) {
    for (j = i+1; j < size && equality = false; j++) {
        if (number [i] + number [j] = x) {
            equality = true;
            }
        }
    }
if (equality = true){
 printf("True.");
 }
else {
printf("No distinct pair.");
}


return ;
} //main
```

Comment: `i` and `j` are undeclared.

Comment: Also, it should be `i < size` not `i <= size`

Comment: And also probably `equality == false`

Comment: ...and equality == true in the if()

Comment: To assign a value to variable you should use `=`, to compare `==`. So i guess if you change if statement to `(number [i] + number [j] == x)` everything will be fine

Comment: Made these changes.
Now getting " 1value required as left operand of assignment" on my "if (number [i] + number [j] = x) {" line.

Comment: See above. Also, "lvalue," as in "left value"

Comment: While we're at it, change `return;` to `return 0;`

Comment: Thank you! It now compiles. However, when I try to execute it immediately says *filename*.exe has stopped working.

Comment: Do not change the question after getting answers. Otherwise it will mislead users to downvote to the answers.

Comment: @LinkNoneya - You might be getting segmentation fault. Look at my answer point 3. You need to define number array properly with some known size.

Answer (score 3):

As this is your homework assignment, I won't give you the entire code ready.
Below are the points which are wrong in your code -

1) Define i and j. `int i,j;` .Don't use %f in scanf when you are declaring variables as int. Use %d everywhere for size,num,etc.

```
scanf("%d", &size);
```

2) Yes assignment operator in if conditions (== and not =) as @Ali Baig posted. `if ( (number [i] + number [j]) == x)` and `if (equality == true)`

3) Assign a static size to number array `int number array[100]` or some size which you feel it enough. If you don't want to use static array then you can dynamiclly allocate array using malloc. You can search more on this.

Comment: Thank you. Point 3 also helped solve the file crashing upon Running. Guess I needed my array to be static.

Comment: Sharp eyes. +1 for pointing dynamic arrays. In C99 there is a feature of using variable length arrays which allow to use array dynamically: `int size = 100;
int number [size];`

Comment: @LinkNoneya - Mark answer correct if you feel you got what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

`i` and `j` are undeclared. Declare them

```
int i, j;
```

Beside of this, your program's **behavior is undefined** as `%f` expects argument of type `float` but `number[i]` is of type `int`. Change `%f` to `%d`.

```
scanf("%d", &number[i]);
```

and same for `scanf("%f", &x);`, `%f` expects argument of type `float` but you are passing `int` tupe argument to it. Change it to

```
scanf("%d", &x);
```

> Also having an error on my if `(number [i] + number [j] = x)` { line. `Error: 1value required as left operand of assignment`}.

As others pointed; assignment operator `=` is not same as equality operator `==`. To check equality conditions you have to use `==` and not `=`. The reason that you are getting the error

```
line. Error: 1value required as left operand of assignment.
```

is left side of an assignment operator always needs an l-value and arithmetic operations results in r-value and hence on the left side of `=` which is not possible in C.

Comment: `i` declared on line 11, so they are in the scope of `main`.

Comment: @imp25; He declared `i` after getting my answer.

Comment: haccks is correct. I wanted to have the most recent code updated in the first post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this too.

```
if ( (number [i] + number [j]) == x)
```

= is an assignment operator while == is used for comparison.